# Tkinter option cursor in Menu class

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-menu

I'm trying to display a different cursor when the mouse arrives on the menu elements, I thought that to do that you had to add the `cursor='something'` option at the options when you create the menu

```
try:
  import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
  import Tkinter as tk

class Settings:
    def __init__(self, master):
        # Elements of the menu
        self.master=master
        self.menu = tk.Menu(root, fg="red")
        self.subMenu = tk.Menu(self.menu, cursor="hand1")

    def openMenu(self):
        # Configuration of the menu
        self.menu.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=self.subMenu)
        self.addOptionsSubMenu()
        self.master.config(menu=self.menu)

    def addOptionsSubMenu(self):
        # Add elements at the sub menu
        self.subMenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=self.quit)
        self.subMenu.add_command(label="Do nothing", command=self.passa)

    # Quit the function
    def quit(self):
        exit()

    # Do nothing
    def passa(self):
        pass

root = tk.Tk()
app = Settings(root)
app.openMenu()
root.mainloop()
```

But as it is the cursor doesn't change, how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The [docs](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/menu.html) for tkinter `Menu` state that the cursor option denotes "**`The cursor that appears when the mouse is over the choices, but only when the menu has been torn off`**". So, I don't think you can actually do what you want. Only when your sub menu has been detached (torn off), you can see your cursor changing. Here is a Demo.

```
import tkinter as tk

class Settings:
  def __init__(self, master):
    # Elements of the menu
    self.master=master
    self.menu = tk.Menu(root, fg="red")
    self.subMenu = tk.Menu(self.menu, cursor="plus")

  def openMenu(self):
    # Configuration of the menu
    self.menu.add_cascade(label="Options", menu=self.subMenu)
    self.addOptionsSubMenu()
    self.master.config(menu=self.menu)

  def addOptionsSubMenu(self):
    # Add elements at the sub menu
    self.subMenu.add_command(label="Quit", command=self.quit)
    self.subMenu.add_command(label="Do nothing", command=self.passa)

  # Quit the function
  def quit(self):
    exit()

  # Do nothing
  def passa(self):
    pass

root = tk.Tk()
app = Settings(root)
app.openMenu()
root.mainloop()
```

[image: Demo]